# When i interchange the commented lines , i receive different output.

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I am learning java abstract window toolkit and i am stuck in this code.When i interchange the commented line, the output changes.Any Explanation for both the cases will be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
public class guibutton
{
public guibutton()
{
Frame f = new Frame("Panel Example");   
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.setBounds(40,80,200,200);
panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
f.add(panel);


f.setVisible(true); ////////////////this line

f.setLayout(null); /////////////////this line

f.setResizable(true);
f.setSize(400,400);

}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new guibutton();
}
}
```

Comment: Please see edits to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

renders your GUI **in its current state**, one where the JFrame's default BorderLayout is in force. Note that BorderLayout ignores the `setBounds(...)` method.

This line:

```
f.setLayout(null);
```

removes the JFrame contentPane's BorderLayout, and so your GUI is rendered without the layout, changing the positioning of the added JPanel -- the `setBounds(...)` method call here is respected.

If you call this *after* the GUI has been rendered, it won't have an effect, unless you do something that triggers the layout managers to re-layout the components, such as re-size the GUI.

Myself, I wouldn't use AWT but would use Swing, I'd draw the rectangle within the paintComponent method of a JPanel, using a Rectangle object. This way, I could monitor the mouse in relation to the rectangle, and change its state. For instance, try out this program, and see what happens to the rectangle when the mouse hovers over it:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GuiButton2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final int RECT_X = 40;
    private static final int RECT_Y = 80;
    private static final int RECT_W = 200;
    private static final Color DEFAULT_RECT_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
    private static final Color HOVER_RECT_COLOR = Color.PINK;
    private Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_W, RECT_W);
    private boolean hover = false;

    public GuiButton2() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                // hover true if mouse is hovering over the rectangle
                hover = rectangle.contains(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // if hover true -- use hover color, otherwise use default color
        Color c = hover ? HOVER_RECT_COLOR : DEFAULT_RECT_COLOR;
        g2.setColor(c);
        g2.fill(rectangle);  // draw rectangle
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GuiButton2 mainPanel = new GuiButton2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Button");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Side note 1:
While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Side note 2:
You will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.